# Counting and Probability Problem

Tags: combinatorics

The question I am having trouble with is how many permutations of six letters{A,B,C,D,E,F} are there that contains neither "BAD" nor "DEF" patterns.

My plan for solving this would be to find the total number of permutations that can be achieved and subtracting the occurrences of "BAD" and "DEF" patterns from that, but I am not sure how to achieve it. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: You may consider $BAD$ as a single letter. Then the number of permutations containing the pattern $BAD$ is $4!$. Similarly, the #of permutations containing $DEF$ is $4!$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Think of BAD as one letter. You have three more. So there are 4! arrangements for these 4 letters. Similarly for DEF.

However there is an overcount. We are counting BADEF twice because we count it in each of our 4! So we must subtract 2 (the cases of C BADEF and BADEF C).

So now we can compute the total number which is 6! and subtract that bad sequences which is 4! + 4! -2

Comment: Note: `BADDEF` uses D twice and doesn't contain `C`.  It's not a permutation of `ABCDEF`.  Nor is `DEFBAD`, by the same reason.  The two permutations over-counted are `BADEFC` and `CBADEF`.

Comment: @GrahamKemp That was a poor slip on my part. Thank you for pointing it out, and now I have fixed it!

Answer (score 1):

The number of permutations containing BAD in any three positions in order is $\binom{6}{3}3!$, and similarly the number of permutations containing DEF is $\binom{6}{3}3!$ (pick three spots to put the pattern then arrange the rest of the letters around it). The number of permutations that contain both BAD and DEF is $\binom{6}{3,3}=\binom{6}{3}$. Thus the number of permutations that contain either BAD or DEF in any three positions in order is
$$2\cdot \binom{6}{3}3!-\binom{6}{3}=11\binom{6}{3}$$

Comment: You can't pick any three spots to put the pattern. They have to be beside each other.

Comment: @pad http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Permutation_pattern

Comment: @pad: Yes, excatly.  The three spots *must* be co-adjacent: `XXX...`, `.XXX..`, `..XXX.`, or `...XXX`  You pick one of the four starting indices, so the count should be ${4\choose 1}3!$, *not* ${6\choose 3}3!$

Comment: @GrahamKemp The word used was "pattern." Pattern doesn't imply adjacent, as shown in the article I linked.

Answer (score 1):

Use the *Law of Complements* and the *Principle of Inclusion and Exclusion*.

Count the total permutations, subtract the counts of those with `BAD` or `DEF`, add back the permutations with both `BAD` and `DEF`.

$$\begin{align}
|T\setminus (B\cup D)| & = |T| -|B|-|D|+|B\cap D|
\\ & = 6! - 4! - 4! + 2!
\\ & = 674
\end{align}$$

Note: To count of permutations containing `DEF` (or `BAD`) permutations of the pattern and 3 other symbols. Ie: {`BAD`,`C`,`E`,`F`}  and {`DEF`,`A`,`B`,`C`}.  Hence $4!$ each for $|B|$ and $|D|$

NOTE 2: To count the permutations that contain both, you must count the permutations of {`BADEF`,`C`}.  Hence $2!$ for $|B\cap D|$